# highChart graficos dinamicos, intervalos de tiempos irregulares

Tags: javascript, array, highcharts

[image: Quiero generar un gráfica similar a esta, con intervalos regulares de tiempo, con la librería highchart]

Utilizo un función en java script, que utiliza un método estático para consultar al servidor, obteniendo como respuesta un `DataSet` con varias tablas sereializado como objeto `JSON`

```
(string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_dsCon);)
```

y lo retorno de esta forma a la funcion `JavaScript`, ya en la funcion JavaScript convierto esta respuesta a formato `JSON`

```
(var json = JSON.parse(resultado.d))
```

Ahora necesito organizar dicho `JSON` de forma que pueda enviarlo a la funcion y que me lo reconozca para que pueda pintar la grafica.

Hasta ahora solo obtengo respuesta del servidor de datos y en la parte del cliente no he avanzado nada, necesito su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Utilizo la libreria `Highcharts`, Graficos de `Lines` con intervalos de tiempos Irregulares.

el resultado de mi respuesta al hacer la llamada Ajax es la siguiente.

```
{
  "Table": [
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "21-Abril-2017",
      "mes": 4,
      "C019Resultado": 8,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "24-Abril-2017",
      "mes": 4,
      "C019Resultado": 2,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "22-Mayo-2017",
      "mes": 5,
      "C019Resultado": 9.5,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "23-Mayo-2017",
      "mes": 5,
      "C019Resultado": 10,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "24-Mayo-2017",
      "mes": 5,
      "C019Resultado": 3.75,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "20-Junio-2017",
      "mes": 6,
      "C019Resultado": 1.1,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "22-Junio-2017",
      "mes": 6,
      "C019Resultado": 1,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "6-Junio-2017",
      "mes": 6,
      "C019Resultado": 16.33,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "4-Agosto-2017",
      "mes": 8,
      "C019Resultado": 4,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "4-Julio-2017",
      "mes": 7,
      "C019Resultado": -2.67,
      "C019CodMaestro": "RDM"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "4-Agosto-2017",
      "mes": 8,
      "C019Resultado": 1,
      "C019CodMaestro": "RDM"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "13-Septiembre-2017",
      "mes": 9,
      "C019Resultado": -10,
      "C019CodMaestro": "RDM"
    }
  ]
}
```

La forma en que la función recibe los datos es la siguiente:

```
series: [{
            name: "Winter 2014-2015",
            data: [
                [Date.UTC(1970, 10, 25), 0],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 6), 0.25],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 20), 1.41],
                [Date.UTC(1970, 11, 25), 1.64],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 4), 1.6],
                [Date.UTC(1971, 0, 17), 2.55],

            ]
        }]
```

con esos datos quiero generar una gráfica como la de la imagen .

Comment: ¿Puedes poner más código? Por ejemplo el formato del dataset _dsCon y la variable resultado.d (que entiendo que será el de una llamada AJAX). Tienes que proveer del máximo de información que nos permite ver el problema

Comment: Podrias ayudarme!

Comment: es primera vez que utilizo este medio y realmente no se como estructurar las preguntas bien

Comment: Mira esto [ask] y [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo aproximado y con comentarios de lo que tendrías que hacer:

```js
var items = {
  "Table": [
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "21-Abril-2017",
      "mes": 4,
      "C019Resultado": 8,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "24-Abril-2017",
      "mes": 4,
      "C019Resultado": 2,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "22-Mayo-2017",
      "mes": 5,
      "C019Resultado": 9.5,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "23-Mayo-2017",
      "mes": 5,
      "C019Resultado": 10,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "24-Mayo-2017",
      "mes": 5,
      "C019Resultado": 3.75,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
     {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "6-Junio-2017",
      "mes": 6,
      "C019Resultado": 16.33,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "20-Junio-2017",
      "mes": 6,
      "C019Resultado": 1.1,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "22-Junio-2017",
      "mes": 6,
      "C019Resultado": 1,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    },   
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "4-Agosto-2017",
      "mes": 8,
      "C019Resultado": 4,
      "C019CodMaestro": "ATP"
    }
  ],
  "Table1": [
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "4-Julio-2017",
      "mes": 7,
      "C019Resultado": -2.67,
      "C019CodMaestro": "RDM"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "4-Agosto-2017",
      "mes": 8,
      "C019Resultado": 1,
      "C019CodMaestro": "RDM"
    },
    {
      "C019FechaIngreso": "13-Septiembre-2017",
      "mes": 9,
      "C019Resultado": -10,
      "C019CodMaestro": "RDM"
    }
  ]
};

var name;
var tables = [];
var auxFecha = [];
//Obtenemos los objetos del JSON (Table y Table1)
var arr = Object.values(items);

//Recorremos los objetos
for (var i in arr){
  var obj = arr[i];
  //Obtenemos el nombre de la serie (ATP y RDM)
  name = obj[0].C019CodMaestro;
  var serie = {};
  serie.name= name;
  serie.data = [];  
  //Obtenemos los puntos UTC de cada serie (ATP y RDM)
    for (var i in obj){
        serie.data[i] = [];
        auxFecha = obj[i].C019FechaIngreso.split("-");
        serie.data[i]= [Date.UTC(auxFecha[2],obj[i].mes-1, auxFecha[0]),obj[i].C019Resultado];    
    }
    //Añadimos la serie al array tables 
    tables.push(serie)    
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Chart de prueba'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Irregular time data in Highcharts JS'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
            month: '%e. %b',
            year: '%b'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Date'
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Snow depth (m)'
        },
        min: -20
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x:%e. %b}: {point.y:.2f} m'
    },

    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                enabled: true
            }
        }
    },

    colors: ['#6CF', '#39F', '#06C', '#036', '#000'],



    // Define the data points. All series have a dummy year
    // of 1970/71 in order to be compared on the same x axis. Note
    // that in JavaScript, months start at 0 for January, 1 for February etc.
    series: tables
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

La solución, básicamente, ha consistido en recorrer el JSON y crear un array de objetos con la estructura aceptada por Highcharts

**Nota**: Tu JSON no venía correctamente ordenado por fechas (el 6 de junio venía después del 20 y del 22) así que he tenido que ordenarlo a mano. Lo ideal es que lo ordenes en tu dataset ya que si no habría que hacer más ingeniería en JS.

Espero que te sirva

Comment: Perfecto, era solo eso, muchas gracias hermano, soy novato en este del desarrollo web y su ayuda era lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias.... @Kiko_L